# image not getting displayed properly

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have this html below

```
<div class="heading-strip bg-3 container-fullscreen">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
</div>
```

My `bg-3` has below css applied to it

```
.bg-3{background-image:url(../images/pictures/3.jpg);
 background-size:cover; }
```

Now I have 7 different dimensions of the same image in my theme. I want to replace the theme image with my image. So I designed my image in all 7 dimensions and replaced them hoping to work it as per the theme which is not working.

Here's related css

```
.bg-1{background-image:url(../images/pictures/1.jpg);   background-size:cover; }
.bg-2{background-image:url(../images/pictures/2.jpg);   background-size:cover; }
.bg-3{background-image:url(../images/pictures/3.jpg);   background-size:cover; }
.bg-4{background-image:url(../images/pictures/4.jpg);   background-size:cover; }
.bg-5{background-image:url(../images/pictures/5.jpg);   background-size:cover; }
.bg-6{background-image:url(../images/pictures/6.jpg);   background-size:cover; }
.bg-7{background-image:url(../images/pictures/7.jpg);   background-size:cover; }

.heading-strip{
padding-top:25px;
padding-bottom:25px;
}

.heading-strip .overlay{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background: linear-gradient( to bottom,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
 )   
}
```

What's the reason and how can I resolve it?

[Here's](http://enableds.com/products/gombo/preview3/) the theme I am talking about. Section below the social icon.

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking for. Obviously if your HTML class (bg-3) doesn't change, neither are your images going to change

Comment: If you can just check the url mentioned. you may understand

Comment: I checked the url and I don't understand :)

Comment: what is happening is because of something, only center part of the image is visible, I want to show the whole image. the image being shown in the mentioned them is not the actual image

Comment: You are still being completely unclear. Post an example of what you have, what is going wrong according to you and what the expected result is. Right now nobody knows what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you have multiple images, but only bg - 3 image is displaying.So
    if you want to display other images one by one you need to use some css markup like this: https: //codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi
        or you can use any jquery plugin
    for this http: //jquery.malsup.com/cycle/